# cdk cfnoutput ignores underscores

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have statements like this in my cdk file:

```
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, 'aws_cognito_region', {
    value: cdk.Stack.of(this).region,
})
```

and when I output it to a file using:

```
cdk deploy --outputs-file ../debug-frontend/src/cdk-config.json
```

and the output looks like this:

```
{
  "StackName": {
    "awscognitoregion": "us-west-1",
  }
}
```

I am really trying to automatically create a proper amplify.config values but it's not working. I prefer to use the Amplify Scoped configuration but I cannot do that with CfnOutput if you guys know a way around this that would be helpful.

https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/client-configuration/configuring-amplify-categories/q/platform/js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do to generate configs from a CDK stack is at the bottom of the deploy code I write to the file using the desired format:

```
writeFileSync('cdk.config.json', JSON.stringify({
  "StackName": {
    "awscognitoregion": ... // Obtain value from CDK code above it
  }
}, null, 2))
```